# How to delete borders in "Full" layout from xmonad default config?

Tags: haskell, configuration, xmonad

Currently I use

```
import XMonad.Layout.NoBorders
...
xmonad $ defaultConfig { layoutHook = noBorders  $  layoutHook defaultConfig }
```

but this makes `noBorder` all the layouts, not just "`Full`".

I know, that I can simply copy `layoutHook` definition from default config and add `noBorder` before "`Full`", but I want the beautiful way, hope Haskell provides some means for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `noBorders`, you could use [`smartBorders`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad-contrib/latest/doc/html/XMonad-Layout-NoBorders.html#v:smartBorders), which hides the border when there's only one window (or a floated window covers the entire screen). That isn't quite the same thing as only hiding it with the `Full` layout, but it might be close enough for your purposes.

Failing that, the best option is probably to copy the default `layoutHook`. It's not very big, and you're quite likely to want to customise it in the future, anyway. You might be able to write a typeclass with instances for all the standard [`LayoutClass`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xmonad/latest/doc/html/XMonad-Core.html#t:LayoutClass)es that applies `noBorders` to `Full`, but it'd be uglier than simply copying the default `layoutHook`.